# Coded UI accessing checkbox in a Grid

Tags: checkbox, coded-ui-tests

I am using codedUI to test a windows application. In one of the screen there is third party grid (code Jock control). I am able to retrieve the Grid as WinTable. I am able to traverse through all the rows and cells inside Grid. I am able to retrieve the text in cell inside the Grid.

**Issue :** For one particular grid there is 3 Columns out of which 1 Contains Check Boxes entirely and remaining 2 Columns Filled with text. I am not able to select that chekbox inside the Grid with coded UI.

I have tried with checked, TryGetClickablePoint properties but not working.

Comment: Please add some code sample.

Comment: Please check the code sample below.